# Can I change an archive page URL with query parameters to be URL with slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to change URLs of custom taxonomy archive pages in my wordpress website.

Now I'm using query string to build each taxonomy archive page.

`example.com/customeposttype/?genre=bbq`

If a user requests URL like above , taxonomy archive of bbq is shown.

Now I'd like to force the URL to be like below.

`example.com/customeposttype/genre/bbq/`

The content of the page should be the same as the content in

> "example.com/customeposttype/?genre=bbq"

Is it possible to rewrite the URL using `add_rewrite_rule()` or by adding some codes to `.htaccess`?

I have tried the code below but it did not work.

```
function my_custom_rewrite() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^/shop/(\w+)/?',
    'index.php/shop/?genre=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite');
```

Comment: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Wp-admin permalink setting you can try using a custom permalink:

Like: /shop/%genre%

[image]